# What is a nucleon field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

A nucleon is either a proton or a neutron. A field is, as John Gribbin says, a physical quantity that has a value for each point in space and time.

But what is meant by a **nucleon field**?

Can anybody give a lucid explanation?

Comment: In the sense of an effective field theory? In nuclear physics one can use an ad-hoc non-relativistic potential to describe nucleons in nuclei. That's a fairly old and partially successful theoretical method, which has lost some luster since we have a pretty good theory of the color force and since people are making advances in lattice qcd.

Comment: The phrase is only meaningful in the context of quantum field theories. Are you familiar with the foundational material of that method?

Comment: @CuriousOne Heck, you can use a *ad hoc* relativistic description too, though few people bother these days because the newer tools you name have really taken over.

Comment: @dmckee: True... but the only thing that I remember about it came from my "Nuclear physics for absolute beginners and other people who never wanted to be in this class" horror. I guess that makes me someone standing in the very shallow end of the nuclear potential. :-)

Comment: Quantum field theory, no not completely versed with it.

Comment: @CuriousOne when I was in graduate school back in 1961 I was in a nuclear physics course on field theory. It was my first introduction to field theoretical tools, and I guess that is why I have a clear distinction in my mind of the "mathematics of field theory" and the reality it models.

Answer (score -1):

Richard Feynman said "fields are just a condition of space."  We have managed to elucidate a small number of fundamental forces in this world.  Each force has a respective quantum field; think of it as a voxel array of tensors, or a matrix associated with every point in space.  Some of these fields are of higher dimensional than others; scalars, spinors, vectors, tensors are all valid.  None of these fields are called the "nucleon field".  It is a made up idea.